# currentFrame of root timeline from inside object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible to pull the currentFrame of the root timeline from inside an object class? Normally a currentFrame call only checks the frame of the movieclip it's attached to within an object class, so how would you go about checking the frame of the entire project from within the object class file?

edit: Nevermind, I found what I was looking for. All you have to do is use `MovieClip(root).currentFrame` and it works just fine. Consider the question answered.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and that'll make the answer easier for other people to see.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours to that. You need 100 reputation to do it before then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I found what I was looking for. All you have to do is **typecast** `root` to `MovieClip` like this:

```
MovieClip(root).currentFrame
```