# AS3 Call method in a frame, from inside a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, call, frame, movieclip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [currentFrame of root timeline from inside object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361838/currentframe-of-root-timeline-from-inside-object)
>   [In flash with as3.0, I have to call a function on the main stage from a movieClip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119794/in-flash-with-as3-0-i-have-to-call-a-function-on-the-main-stage-from-a-moviecli)

I have this method in a frame on my scene:

`function toggleStreaming():void
{
    //something
}`

and I would like to be able to call that method from within a movieClip, how do I point to the method?

Comment: @MartyWallace Don't make edits like that, as we have to roll them back as the banner is duplicated.

Comment: @casperOne Not sure what you mean, but no probs...

Comment: @MartyWallace The ["Duplicate header" banner](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9421641/3) that you placed in the question.  It will get placed there automatically if/when closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the frame containing the function is the main timeline you could use:

```
MovieClip(root).toggleStreaming();
```